# How is $|J_k u(x)|$ (appearing in the corea formula) defined when $Du$ does not have full rank?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I quote from wiki:

> The coarea formula can be applied to Lipschitz functions $u$ defined
>   in $Ω ⊂ \mathbb R^n$, taking on values in $\mathbb R^k$ where $k < n$.
>   In this case, the following identity holds $$\int_\Omega g(x) |J_k u(x)|\, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \left(\int_{u^{-1}(t)}g(x)\,dH_{n-k}(x)\right)\,dt$$
>
> where $J_ku$ is the $k$-dimensional Jacobian of $u$.

I know that if $Du$ has full rank, $|J_k u(x)|=\sqrt{\det DuDu^T}$. But when $Du$ does not have full rank, how is $|J_k u(x)|$ defined?

Comment: then it is zero

Comment: So this means the coarea formula fails? I am doubtful about that

Comment: For convenience: Now reposted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/262375/how-is-j-k-ux-in-the-corea-formula-defined-when-du-does-not-have-full